# Custom Shaped progress View

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I'm looking out for some solution regarding the custom progress view.

Basically, i would like to fill the image below to represent the loading progress,just like the one's we have in games.

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve it??

Comment: Mask it anyway you like - with non-transparent UIView or use CGMaskRef - and tie mask height to loading progress. Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can u please guide me to the masking functionality? m noob in CG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masking using CoreGraphics:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagetomask.png"];
CGImageRef maskRef = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"].CGImage;
CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                                CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                                CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef maskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMask([img CGImage], mask);
[imageView setImage:maskedImage];
```

Your `mask.png` should be non-transparent image filled like inverted alpha - black for visible parts, white for transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom view class and add animation sequence in that class to show your images in sequence infinitly.

Add that view to mainwindow like this
(UIWindow*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];

call bringSubviewToFront to show that view on any view where u want this loading screen(view).