# Custom UIView to display progress with dots instead of bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiprogressview

[image: Progress Bar]

I'm trying to setup a view that will display progress with these dots instead of a solid bar. Ideally, I'd like to have the dots fill vertically (Bottom to top).

I have two UIImageViews inside of a UIView, one for the grey background and one with the foreground masked.

```
 UIImage * bgImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prog_bg.png"];
    UIImageView * bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImg];
    progImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prog.png"];
    maskRef = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prog_mask.png"].CGImage;
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef maskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMask([progImage CGImage], mask);
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImage];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [progView addSubview:bgView];
    [progView addSubview:imageView];
```

I found the code in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140030/custom-shaped-progress-view). I can't seem to define the width of the mask from my delegate that updates the progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `CGImageGetWidth(maskRef) * percentage` in `CGImageMaskCreate`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Would I need to also recreate the mask each time an update to the progress occurs? Just putting that code in had no effect.